# Как вращать башню вокруг оси Y при перемещении мыши (THREE.JS)

Tags: javascript, three.js

Как вращать башню вокруг оси Y при перемещении мыши (THREE.JS)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, башня отдельный объект

Comment: И в чем заключается проблема? Заводите переменную, в которой приводите перемещение мыши к желаемому углу поворота. А в отрисовке башню рисуете с этим углом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, но он не правильно работает

```
 document.onmousemove = event => {
        this.mouse.x = event.clientX;
        this.mouse.y = event.clientY;
        let angle = Math.atan2(
            this.mouse.y - this.map.getCenterMap().y,
            this.mouse.x - this.map.getCenterMap().x
        ) *
            180 /
            Math.PI;
        this.player.player.tower.rotation.y = angle * DEG_TO_RAD;
    };
```

Comment: нашел проблему, нужно было брать центр экрана, а не карты